# Set a different hero image on main layout according to the post/url (retrieving the data from graphQL) [GATSBY]

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, yaml-front-matter

**EDIT**: There is a demo on this [Github repository](https://github.com/anonimoconiglio/gatsby-for-debugging).

I need to change the main layout hero-image of my blog according to the post/page (its slug).
Every post has a hero-image, setted in the frontmatter info.

I tried everything but:
1. either it shows only the same image (of my last post) - this happens if I recall `markdownRemark` without iterate.
2. Or it tells me that I need a key props (that I already set) after iterate with `allMarkdownRemark`.

This is my last attempt.
I grabbed the data via GraphQl and then setted a condition (if it's the homepage it shows my main hero-image, otherwise it should show the image that is located in frontmatter  info of the single post):

```
[...]
{location.pathname === '/' 
  ? (<Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />) 
  : (({allMarkdownRemark}) => ( 
    allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({node}) => ( 
      <Img 
        key={node.frontmatter.slug}
        fluid={node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid} /> 
    )
  ))
)}
[...]
```

This is the entire layout component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { Spring } from 'react-spring/renderprops';
import styled from "styled-components";
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import Img from 'gatsby-image';


import Header from "./header";
import Archive from "./archive";
import "./layout.css";

const MainLayout = styled.main`...`;

const Layout = ({ children, location }) => (
<StaticQuery
  query={graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
          description
        }
      }
      file(relativePath: {regex: "/my-main-img/"}) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid (maxWidth: 1900, quality: 90) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
          } 
        }
      }
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              slug
              hero {
                childImageSharp{
                  fluid(maxWidth: 800, quality: 100) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      markdownRemark {
        frontmatter {
          hero {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid (maxWidth: 1900, quality: 90) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  `}
  render={data => (
    <>
      <Helmet [...]>
      [...]
      </Helmet>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
      <Spring 
        from={{ height: location.pathname === '/' ? 150 : 500 }} 
        to={{ height: location.pathname === '/' ? 500 : 150 }}>
        {({ height }) => 
          <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', height }}>
            {location.pathname === '/'
              ? (<Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />)
              : (({allMarkdownRemark}) => ( 
                    allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({node}) => 
                      (<Img
                        key={node.frontmatter.slug}
                        fluid={node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid}/>)
                    )
                ))
            }
          </div>
        }
      </Spring>
      <MainLayout>
        <div>{children}</div>
        <Archive />
      </MainLayout>
    </>
    )}
  />
);

Layout.propTypes = {
children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default Layout;
```

I followed every guide but still don't get what's missing. I'm new to react and not so expert in javascript, sorry if this is a noob question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', height }}>
    {location.pathname === '/'
      ? (<Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />)
>     : (({allMarkdownRemark}) => ( 
>           allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({node}) => 
>             (<Img
>               key={node.frontmatter.slug}
>               fluid={node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid}/>)
>           )
>       ))
    }
  </div>
```

Maybe this is the problem -- in the ternary above, you're passing in a function for the false condition, even though it doesn't look like there's a render props component above it? Perhaps it should just be

```
{ location.pathname === '/' 
    ? (<Img ... />)
    : (data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => ...))
}
```

Comment: mm this worked in part (I added a parentesis between  "{node}" ):

EDIT:  
`data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => <Img key={node.frontmatter.slug} fluid={node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid} /> )`

the problem is that there is always the same image, other than the main-hero-image, whatever post I visit there is alwayts the hero image of the first post.

Comment: it's like it doesn't iterate, it keeps only the image of the first post founded in the query.

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, there should be parenthesis between `{node}`. Will edit. So it shows many instance of the same image? Does it iterate at all? Are you sure the path in each markdown is pointing to a unique image?

Comment: yes, there are 3 posts with a unique image. I just remove that "overflow hidden" and now I see all three images, despite I'm in the /post/first-post.

EDIT: do you think I should iterate `markdownRemark` instead? is that possible?

Comment: I think I understand my problem but I don't know how to implement it: I maybe need some "context". The reason because its showing me all 3 images it's because I'm telling him to do that (its iterating all the images on the mk posts and for each one is showing an Img). I need to use `markdownRemark` like in my post component, but for this I need a page query with variables, and since I'm trying to modify the main layout (that it's not a page) I can't use a page query here. It's there a way to pass data from the page query to the main layout? Like a prop but in the contrary way.

Comment: @Santiago I doubt that's what you need to do though, it should pass you different image paths if you do have different image paths. If your repo can be shared, I'll be happy to take a look if you add it to the question or pm me

Comment: hello Derek, sorry for the late response. I manage to make a demo on github, if you want to take a look. Here it is: https://github.com/anonimoconiglio/gatsby-for-debugging
All the config is on the springhero.js component.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Santiago Looks like you want springhero.js to display the image of each blogpost, when you go to that post? There're 3 things you can do: (1) query all post's image & match them based on path (2) pass image to this component in your postLayout.js (you'd need to include Layout.js and not use gatsby-plugin-layout) and (3) keep gatsby-plugin-layout, but use something like React's context api to pass image to springhero.js. Seeing how simple the blog is, I'd advise you to try no. 2

Comment: Hello Derek! I think I already tried the option n°1 and it doesn't work (maybe I wasn't matching them correctly? I tried with "key" attribute/prop). The n°2 did it! But now I have to move the Archive (sidebar) and the MainLayout components outside the layout. Better than nothing I guess. Although, I'm interested in learning the n°3 solution. Is it difficult? Is there any guide do you recommend? Thank you very much for the help!!